# Rake assets:precompile but image file doesn't show on website sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm ripping some hair out wondering why this isn't working. In one of my JS files, I have the following code:

```
map.loadImage('markergroup.svg', function(error, image) {
    console.log(image);
});
```

Then, I have `markergroup.svg` location in `app/assets/images`.

When I run `rake assets:precompile` , I see the `markergroup.svg` image was properly precompiled yet on the localhost I'm getting the file isn't showing under `sources`.

All of my other images are showing up however, would anymore know why I can't load this file?

Comment: try 'assets/markergroup.svg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the JS file (`example.js`) to JS ERB file (`example.js.erb`).

Then, you can use the ERB helper method `asset_path` to find the precompiled asset public URL as below:

```
map.loadImage("<%= asset_path('markergroup.svg') %>", function(error, image) {
    console.log(image);
});
```